# Value 0 or null when send a json from angular to c#

Tags: c#, json, api, angular, post

I have a problem with my project on Angular&C#. I'm a begginer and i have this problem. When I send a json from angular to C # (POST), although json has value, c # doesn't get anything (value 0 for int and null for string). I don't know what i'm doing wrong. The Json has this structure :

```
[{"delegacion":11,"municipio":1,"ejercicio":2017,"ninterno":-1,"tipo":"T"}]
```

My code

Angular

```
preparaTarea(){    
this.data.push({'delegacion':this.delegacion,
                    'municipio':this.municipio,
                    'ejercicio':this.ejercicio,
                    'ninterno':this.ninterno,
                    'tipo':this.tipo_producto});

     this._DelegationService.sendPtipo(this.data)
        .subscribe(res=>{
                this.data = res;
              },             
              (err) =>console.log(err));  


    }

sendPtipo(data){
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let urlPtipo ='http://localhost:50790/ApiProductoTipo/CalculaPTRecinto';

        let body = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(body);

    return this._http.post(urlPtipo , body , options)
                   .map(data => {alert('ok');})
                   .catch(this.handleError);
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }}
```

c#

```
public class MyObj
        {
            public int delegacion { get; set; }
            public int municipio { get; set; }
            public int ejercicio { get; set; }
            public int ninterno { get; set; }
            public string tipo { get; set; }

        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("~/ApiProductoTipo/CalculaPTRecinto")]
        public HttpResponseMessage CalculaPTRecinto([FromBody]MyObj data)
        {                
            var delegacion = data.delegacion;
            var municipio = data.municipio;
            var recinto = data.ninterno;
            var ejercicio = data.ejercicio;
            var tipo = data.tipo;    


            if (this.productoTipoService.CalculaPTRecinto(delegacion, municipio, recinto, ejercicio, tipo) != 0)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        }
```

When i debug, the values of delegacion, municipio etc has 0 value, and null for tipo. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: try to post hard code data by caring of order of properties and also check that you should not be posting array

Comment: It would be much better if you use either Postman or fiddler to check your rest endpoint first and after successfully checking of that then proceed with hard coded object and then in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem doing this

```
  preparaTarea() {
     //Changing array by this
    let datos = { "delegacion":this.delegacion,
                  "municipio":this.municipio,
                  "ejercicio":this.ejercicio,
                  "ninterno":this.ninterno,
                  "tipo":this.tipo_producto
                  };  

    this._CalculoPTService.sendPtipo(datos)
      .subscribe(res => {
        datos = res;
      },
      (err) => console.log(err));
  }
```